# "canonical" way to use logging for Python asserts

Tags: python, logging

In this following code, `assert` is used outside of unit test:

```
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("info level")
    assert 1 == 0
```

which prints as follows:

```
2016-02-16 14:56:58,445 - __main__ - INFO - info level
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "logtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert 1 == 0
AssertionError
```

What is the "canonical" way to use the timestamped logging format for `AssertionError` raised by the `assert` (possibly without rewriting each `assert` in the code)?

There were a number of similar questions asked, mostly dealing with `asserts` in unit testing context ...
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539897/need-py-test-to-log-assert-errors-in-log-file-from-python-logging-module

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088879/is-there-a-way-to-configure-python-logging-to-log-content-or-context-of-assert-f

Comment: To clarify, you just want the raised `AssertionError` to be written to some logging handler instead of printed to `stderr`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191830/best-way-to-log-a-python-exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643327/sys-excepthook-and-threading

Comment: You don't have to wrap each and every assert separately, just wrap the top level of your program, or use `sys.excepthook`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58095587/192373

Answer (score 10):

When you're dealing with logging an exception, you have the code that may error in a `try except` and then log the exception, for example:

```
try:
    assert 1 == 0 
except AssertionError as err:
    logger.exception("My assert failed :( ")
    raise err
```

Then it would log:

```
2016-02-16 15:29:43,009 - __main__ - INFO - info level
2016-02-16 15:29:43,009 - __main__ - ERROR - My assert failed :( 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/PycharmProjects/scratchyard/test_time.py", line 8, in <module>
    assert 1 == 0
AssertionError
```

Comment: This would require wrapping all assert statements. Also this code doesn't exit when the assert fails, so it isn't exactly equivalent ...

Comment: Correct for first part. Second part, you can make it stop by either still raising the error (as edit now shows) or making a call to `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Agree with @gliptak: this answer isn't really helpful because it requires too much manual labor. There should be a policy to set that will log *all* assertions.

Comment: @Robert P. Goldman as I see it that's not necessarily true... as long as you want either all of them to be raised or all of them to be ignored you could also wrap everything in a `main()` function and then put the call to the `main()` function in a `try except AssertionError` and log and/or raise all assertions as you wish without having to wrap each one individually...   (if you want to give one of them a special treatment you can still catch it individually before it is raised and treated by the general catch)