# catch exceptions in pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest

is there a way to catch all exceptions in a pytest fixture? what I want to do is create a pytest fixture with scope="function" and autouse=True that will catch all exceptions in any of the tests and log the exception. I already have some test cases written and don't want to go and add try/except in every single one of them.

Comment: If you catch all exceptions in a test, it will never fail. Are you sure this is what you are after? Tests are different from production code.

Comment: I mean what I am trying to do really is catch it, log it and raise the exception again. I just want the logs to have the exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12547816/7364289. it uses pytest_runtest_call hook in conftest to log and raise exception